# Block a day of the week during a particular month using DateRangePicker

Tags: reactjs, react-dates

Using the `DateRangePicker` from [react-dates](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates#daterangepicker), I wish to disable Mondays, but only during the months of July and August. React is new to me and I don't know how to start solving this problem.

The documentation has a [blockedDays](http://airbnb.io/react-dates/?selectedKind=DRP%20-%20Day%20Props&selectedStory=blocks%20fridays&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel) prop, but it is not clear to me how I should use it for my particular case.

How can I access the currently displayed month and how can I subsequently block Mondays?

For those who wish to see my code, I have made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/heleneshaikh/0f959d2bd66e97b1b3ef7a4ec2e63083).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the `isDayBlocked` prop.

This prop is a function callback that will send you a [`moment` date](https://momentjs.com/), and require you to send a boolean back, `true` meaning that the day is blocked and `false` meaning the opposite.

According to the [moment documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/), here is how you will know if your day should be blocked or not :

```
isDayBlocked = momentDate => {
    if (momentDate.format('ddd') === 'Mon' && ['Jul', 'Aug'].includes(momentDate.format('MMM')) return true

    return false
}
```

The following condition would work as well (refer to the doc link above) :

```
momentDate.format('d') === 0 && [6, 7].includes(momentDate.format('M')
```

Short syntax :

```
isDayBlocked = momentDate => momentDate.format('d') === 0 && [6, 7].includes(momentDate.format('M')
```

And here is the picker :

```
<DateRangePicker
    isDayBlocked={this.isDayBlocked}
    // ... your other props
/>
```

---

I think I found it. In the code you gave me, you declare the `isDayBlocked` prop twice :

```
            isDayBlocked={day1 => this.state.disabledDates.some(day2 => isSameDay(day1, day2))} //First time
            startDateId="datePickerStart"
            endDateId="datePickerEnd"
            onDatesChange={this.onDatesChange}
            onFocusChange={this.onFocusChange}
            focusedInput={focusedInput}
            startDate={startDate}
            endDate={endDate}
            minimumNights={minimumNights}
            isOutsideRange={condition}
            isDayBlocked = {momentDate => momentDate.format('d') === 0 } // Second one
```

You can merge them in a single function as shown in my first bit of code and put both conditions inside :

```
isDayBlocked = momentDate => {
    if (momentDate.format('ddd') === 'Mon' && ['Jul', 'Aug'].includes(momentDate.format('MMM')) return true

    if(this.state.disabledDates.some(day2 => isSameDay(day1, day2))) return true

    return false
}
```

Following your comment, you have 2 solutions.

Converting the values you want to test to strings :

```
momentDate => momentDate.format('d') === '0' && ['6','7'].includes(momentDate.format('M')
```

Or using the non-strict operator :

```
momentDate => momentDate.format('d') == 0 && ['6', '7'].includes(momentDate.format('M')
```

Comment: Thank you. To test your approach, I simplified it like this (directly in the picker): 
`isDayBlocked = {momentDate => momentDate.format('d') === 0 }`, which doesn't disable any dates at all. It should return true (and thus disable) every Monday. Any ideas?

Comment: Umm, weird, is there a reason for the function you pasted to be surrounded by brackets or is it a typo ? Also, can you console.log out the result of the formatted date ?

Comment: The console.log logs integers between 0 and 6, so that seems to be correct. The brackets are required here ( https://gist.github.com/heleneshaikh/0f959d2bd66e97b1b3ef7a4ec2e63083#file-app-js-L125 )

Comment: I think I figured it out

Comment: `momentDate.format('d)` returns a `string` representation of the week index, so a strict comparison with an `int` would not work as used in your example.